How can I clean drywall mud off black tile grout?
Black grout and black tile were just installed as a part of a larger renovation job. Our contractor dripped drywall mud onto it. In the Process of trying to clean the tile off, drywall mud particles have smeared into the grout, giving it a white-washed appearance. I have used soapy water and a rag several times. It has not improved the appearance.
Any ideas how to wash away the white and restore the pretty black color?
It has not yet been sealed.


Try compressed air, after the water from the soap and rag thoroughly dries. (On a hidden portion first.)
A rag pushes the white particles into the grout further. You need something to get up under the white stuff to make it want to come off. Compressed air might do that.

I would soak the area and agitate gently with a nylon brush, then vacuum with a wet/dry vac.
After that, look at staining the grout with a suitable product to hide any remaining material.

Cleaning white from black grout is like trying to put toothpaste back into the tube. Darn impossible.
The grout needs To be scraped down and redone.

In my experience, black grout will ALWAYS become a splotchy dark gray in short order, unless installed and maintained in an inhuman "clean room" environment.
